# How to add specific class on selected material table row (Angular Material Table)?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I want to use the angular material table which should return a class for table row when it triggers click on it.

tableRowClicked() should return the class name.

```
<tr    mat-row               
       *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"               
       [class]="tableRowClicked()"               
       (click)="productSelect(row)"></tr>


 getRowClass(row: any): any {
           return {
    'is-selected': row.id === this.currentId
 };   }

 

tr {     
   &.is-selected{       background: red; }
   }
```

I tried to change the selected row background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by making use of the [class.selected] template directive which usually returns a boolean based on a certain condition on your rendered template.

eg.

```
<tr mat-row (click)="clickedRow(row)" [class.row-clicked]="row.number === currentRowID"
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
  </tr>
```

**clickedRow(row)** is a ts function which accepts the table row as a parameter.
**currentRowID** is a variable that holds a unique identifier for the current row.

```
  clickedRow(row: any) {
this.currentRowID = row.number
console.log(data)
```

}

[class**.row-clicked**] .row-clicked is a class that has the styled property for the selected row.

This [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#style-the-selected-hero) on Angular official website can be helpful.